# How to do a partial page refresh with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two separate navigable areas on my site. The lefthand column has its own navigation, and the righthand column (the main content area) has its own set of links:

[image: Screenshot of the Content Areas]

I'd like to be able to press on a link on the left-hand side (like "Resume", "Email", etc.) and only load the new page within that lefthand sidebar (without refreshing the entire browser window).

I am using divs to load the right side's (main content) navigation, and the entire sidebar's content:

```
 <script>
  $.get("navigation.html", function(data){
    $(".nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
  });

  $.get("sidebar-content1.html", function(data){
    $(".sidebar").replaceWith(data);
  });
```

I'm doing basically the same thing for the lefthand sidebar to load its three links:

```
<script>
  $.get("sidebar-navigation.html", function(data){
    $(".sidebar-nav").replaceWith(data);
  });
</script>
```

When I press on a link that's inside the left sidebar, how do I just refresh that pink area?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you might find JQuery's `.on()` and `.load()` functions useful here.

The `.on()` method allows you to [bind event handlers to DOM elements that are not currently present](https://api.jquery.com/on/) in the page, which is useful in your case seeing that the contents of `navigation.html` are dynamically added to the page.

The `.load()` [method is a helper](https://api.jquery.com/load/) that basically achieves what you're doing with `$.get()` and `$.replaceWith()` via a single method call.

For details on how these can work together, see the comments below:

```
/*
Use $.on() to associate a click handler with any link nested under .sidebar-nav, 
even if the links are dynamically added to the page in the future (ie after a 
$.get())
*/
$('body').on('click', '.sidebar-nav a', function() {

  /*
  Get the href for the link being clicked
  */
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  /*
  Issue a request for the html document
  or resource at href and load the contents
  directly into .sidebar if successful
  */
  $('.sidebar').load(href);

  /*
  Return false to prevent the link's default
  navigation behavior
  */
  return false;
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ooh, this is much closer to what I was trying to do. I'm running into a couple of bugs, but I think I can figure it out from here... thanks so much!

Comment: I do have one follow up question. When I press on the same link twice, the entire navigation bar disappears. Sometimes the main content area's content goes into the sidebar too. I was wondering if you had any ideas? I have `<div class="sidebar-content"></div>` as a container for the entire sidebar and `<div class="sidebar-nav"></div>` to dynamically load the links.

Comment: @Katherine you're welcome! please consider accepting the answer if it has helped with your original question :-) (by clicking the grey tick icon)

Comment: The issue with the navigation bar disappearing may be causes by some other javascript on your page. Can you share a link to your project, or a link to jsFiddle with all of your code?

Comment: Hi, done. Here's a link to my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p1qu2t3h/#&togetherjs=pnJ3ClbRuS . I have a separate file with `sidebar-navigation.html` that just contains a div `nav-container` with four links.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use replaceWith method of jQuery, that is for returning the replaced elements which you don't have any in this example. You can use `$(".sidebar").html(data)`

For the links to load in another div, you could do something like this right after you load navigation links.

```
// this will interfere all the links would load inside sidebar-nav div
$("div.sidebar-nav a").click(function(event) {
  var urlToGet = $(this).attr("href"); // gets the url of the link
  $.get(urlToGet, function(data) { // loads the url
    $("div.main-content").html(data); // puts the loaded url content to main-content 
  });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Ah! I want to load the links within the same div. So clicking on "About", "Resume", etc would load the content in the pink area, & leave the white area unrefreshed. I tried this, but didn't have any success:<script>
      $("div.nav-container a").click(function(event) {
        var urlToGet = $(this).attr("href"); // gets the url of the link
        $.get(urlToGet, function(data) { // loads the url
          $("div.sidebar-content").html(data); // puts the loaded url content to sidebar-content 
        });

        event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>`

Comment: Then just change the `$("div.main-content").html(data);` to `$("div.sidebar").html(data);`

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. I am wondering if its because `nav-container` is in a separate file with just my sidebar navigation links? Sorry for all the formatting issues...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below example.(JQUERY)

```
<div id="div3" class="left">
    <button onclick="refresh()" id="refresh">
        Refresh
    </button>
</div>

<div id="div4" class="right"></div>

var content="<h1>refreshed</h1>"
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#refresh').click(function(){
            $('#div3').html(content); //it will just overrides the previous html
        });
    });
```